# NSUserDefaults loses stored values third time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I used `NsUserDefaults` for login page.

First I enter username and password, push sub `viewcontroller` then I come again login page and automatically login and push subviewcontroller (I can login automatically 2 times) but third one page stay in login page because of the username and password value empty
oturumAcikMi is equal to session

When I write my code in `viewDidLoad`, I get error message like below so my code is in `viewDidAppear`

nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar 
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <...: 0xcda4250>. 
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

My code

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSObject *session = [def objectForKey:@"sessionUsr"]; 
NSLog(@"%@ ?????", session); 
if(session != nil && ![session isEqual:@""]) 
{ 
[self ConnectToService]; 
} 
} 

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser { 
NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 

[def setObject:self.eposta.text forKey:@"sessionUsr"]; 
[def setObject:self.sifre.text forKey:@"sessionPass"]; 
[def synchronize]; 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this works.  Why do you store the username/password when you finish parsing the XML document?  How is the username/password related to the XML document?

Comment: What you are doing if the parse fails.

Comment: Don't use NSUserDefaults for passwords. It's not designed for sensitive information. That sort of things can be stored in the keychain.

Comment: I store username and password in parserDidEndDocument, because I check username and password correct via web service.

Comment: Make sure you call `NSUserDefaults -synchronize` on the main thread as otherwise it is asynchronous related to the main thread where you push vc.

Comment: Why third time username and password values are empty?

Comment: I solved my problem.
I wrote if(session != nil && ![session isEqual:@""]) before NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; in parserDidEndDocument